# docker orchestration - connect to remote interpreter using pycharm

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, amazon-ecs

i'm trying to connect pycharm to docker remote interpreter, but the container is part of a cluster (specifically using AWS ECS cluster)

i can not access the container directly i have to go through the bastion machine (the instance that is running the container do not have public IP)

i.e to access the container i need to access it via bastion machine

i had an idea of using ssh tunneling but i could not figure out how to do so using pycharm docker utility

is there any solution that pycharm suggests for that?